# Why do we use much prettier but not much interesting?

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions

Here is the passage from the text I've just read:

> I think this material is **much prettier** than that, don't you?
>
> Well, the design is **more interesting** and the colors are brighter.

---

I wonder, can we say much interesting instead of more interesting in this situation?

It says much prettier but then it says more interesting which confuses me a bit.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Much" is an intensifier, an adverb which can modify a comparative adjective like "prettier". "More interesting" is a comparative adjective and you can intensify it: "much more interesting".